# JQuery DatePicker for C# Razor Input

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I have this form that uses C# Razor html helper for its form input (for date):

```
<label>Application Date</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Loan.DateApplication, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepick" })<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Loan.DateApplication)
```

And somewhere in my script, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepick').datepicker();
});
```

I wanted that input box to have a date picker but this one doesn't work. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's little information to debug this... Is your view a partial view? Do you load it using AJAX? Is your script file loaded?

Comment: No its not a partial view, and the script is in my view, just inside <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: In browser console when I click the textbox, it gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

Comment: @AndreiV this 'msie' is inside the jquery ui library file itself, its not mine.

Comment: Do you load the jQuery UI scripts before you call `.datepicker()`? This is often the case, when the scripts are loaded at the end of the body, in `_Layout.cshtm`.

Comment: No, JQuery UI scripts are loaded at the top of the _Layout.cshtm. Actually this was working before. Then my mate said he updated JQuery, should that be a problem if he updated JQuery to 1.9.1 and JQuery UI is 1.8.24

Comment: Should not be a problem. You could try to clear the cache of your browser since the old files might still be there.

Comment: @AndreiV Weird, i tried to rollback the update from 1.9.1 to 1.8.3 and now my datepicker works. Maybe I should read more of the changelogs..